# Query with a logical expression comparing field values

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to do a simple mongo query which resembles like this SQL

```
Select * from insights where category = 1 and param_count > param_mean + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would use [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) as an aggregation expression for this, coupled with an initial [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to at least possibly use an index for the non-calculated expression:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$match": { "category": 1 } },
   { "$redact": {
     "$cond": {
       "if": { "$gt": [ "$param_count", { "$add": [ "$param_mean", 1 ] } ] },
       "then": "$$KEEP",
       "else": "$$PRUNE"
     }
   }}
])
```

If your MongoDB "server" version is less than 2.6 without the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) operator, then you can use [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) which evaluates a JavaScript expression to boolean to return results:

```
db.collection.find({
  "category": 1,
  "$where": "this.param_count > this.param_mean + 1"
})
```

Which while shorter in syntax, it takes considerable more processing time due to the need to evaluate the JavaScript expression.

Where possible, then you should use [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/), or avoid calculations altogether and store the calculated evaluation in the document instead. That last statement is true for "all" databases really.